# How to convert Excel-VBA from Windows to MAC?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'd like to run the below macro, which runs fine on Windows, in Excel for Mac. The macro saves the `ActiveWorkBook` (in a specific directory) and sends it via email.

```
Sub SauveEnvoi()

  Dim file As String
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  file = Macros.Cells(4, 2).Value & Macros.Cells(1, 2).Value
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs file
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show Macros.Cells(2, 2).Value, Macros.Cells(3, 2).Value
  SetAttr file, vbReadOnly
  Application.Quit
End Sub
```

**From Comments below**

`Macros.Cells(4, 2)` being equal to `C:\LPO Solutions\Commandes OGY\`,
`Macros.Cells(1, 2)` being equal to `CDE.xlsm`,
`Macros.Cells(2, 2)` being equal to `xxxx@yyyy.fr`,
`Macros.Cells(3, 2)` being equal to `Commandes`

Comment: Macros.Cells(4, 2) being equal to C:\LPO Solutions\Commandes OGY\, 
Macros.Cells(1, 2) being equal to CDE.xlsm, 
Macros.Cells(2, 2) being equal to xxxx@yyyy.fr, 
Macros.Cells(3, 2) being equal to Commandes

Comment: You may want to see [This](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mail.htm)

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, this link is great for sending email from MAC what about saving files? Thanks

Comment: Saving files? Which files and where?

Comment: file = Macros.Cells(4, 2).Value & Macros.Cells(1, 2).Value
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs file

Comment: I understood that the path "C:\Luisa\" for instance, doesn't work under MAC? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I got confused as you said files and not file. So you want to save the `Activeworkbook` first. right?

Comment: Indeed, thanks. Sorry but it is the first time I'm on this forum so not veru used with it :-)

Comment: correct in Mac the path separator is ":" and not "\". You can get that by using `Application.Pathseparator` Also it doesn't have "C:"  I don't have access to MAC. If you type `?thisworkbook.Path` in Immediate window, you can see what the root directory is. It would be of the format `Mac HD:Documents:myfile` Provided the file has been saved once...